# Why are questions with no close votes in the close review queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I have just been asked to review a few questions for closing that don’t seem to have any close votes,  e.g. [Upgrade Windows Store app which includes SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035317/upgrade-windows-store-app-which-includes-sqlite)